# Reading names of the indexes from kafka topic doesn't work

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have a problem writing a spark job. The problem goes as follows. I need to process all records from elasticsearch index. Spark seems like a good match for this and I wrote following code

```
val dataset: Dataset<Row> = session.read()
    .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
    .option("es.read.field.include", "orgUUID,serializedEventKey,involvedContactURNs,crmAssociationSmartURNs")
    .option("es.read.field.as.array.include", "involvedContactURNs,crmAssociationSmartURNs")
    .load(index)
dataset.foreach(transform)
```

This code works without problem and does everything as expected - the problem is that index - (name of the elasticsearch index) is not known a-priory. I have to read names of the indexes from kafka topic. So I have added following loop

```
while (true) {
    val records = kafkaClient.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
    if (!records.isEmpty) {
        records.forEach { record ->
            val index = record.value()
            // Here comes code from above to process index
        }
    }
```

This somehow doesn't work - the same records got read multiple times from the same kafka topic. I understand that spark spawns multiple executors behind the back still all kafka clients share the same group ID and according to kafka documentation only one of them should be able to read - that is the first mystery to which I want to get some explanation.
That is not the end of my adventure though. I decided to use spark streaming to read from kafka and went with the following

```
val df = session.readStream()
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    .option("subscribe", "test_consumers")
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
    .load()
```

and after that

```
val temp = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)","CAST(value AS STRING)")
val temp1 = temp.map(retrieve, Encoders.STRING())

val retrieve: MapFunction<Row, String> = MapFunction { row ->
    val index = row.getAs("value")
    // Here initial block of code to process elasticsearch index
    index
}
```

This failed with

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Writing job aborted.
```

At the line in the initial code block `dataset.foreach(transform)`

Comment: Did you forget `kafkaClient.commitSync`? Otherwise, there's nothing preventing duplicates in your topic, anyway. And I don't think you can use SparkSession object within a processing method... I personally would use direct Elasticsearch SDK here, but Can you share the full stacktrace?

Comment: I didn't forget commitSync I've tried both auto.commit.offset=false with commitSync immediately after poll and auto.commit.offset=true without commitSync - the result was the same the value was read multiple times and what is even more strange it was read at exactly the same millisecond according to splunk log

Comment: You can set `kafka.group.id`, by the way. Did those logs include the client id? In any case, like I said, I've seen errors before trying to use `spark.read` (or `session.read`) inside of any `foreach` Spark action because the SparkSession actions are intended to be ran by the driver, not within each executor